# Possible to make an app script provide realtime info pulling from a dynamic spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a dynamic spreadsheet that pulls data every minute.
I have an Apps Script that displays this data in a formatted table.
I was wondering if there is a way to have it refresh the data every minute or so?
I tried setting up the following, and linking resetForm() to a trigger...  but that doesn't work.  Triggers only run on the server... not the client.  If I refresh the page the new values come in.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

```
function resetForm(e){
var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
app.remove(0);
return createApp(app);
}

function doGet(e){
return createApp(UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Enterprise Operations Requests'));
}

function createApp(e){

var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
//This is where I have the code for the table with dynamic data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no onTimer function in Google Apps Scripts that you can use to achieve this functionality. However, there is a convoluted workaround that I had provided as a reply to a question in the old forum ( http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!mydiscussions/apps-script/2pqhh_eTIvQ ).

Please take a look at the code I posted there and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: I suppose this could work...  But it looks like the script would just run indefinitely, am I understanding this correct?  And also, what would you think about setting a for function that calls the app 60 or so times, and contains a Utilities.sleep(1min) in between each call of the function that builds the app?

Comment: The script will run as long as the UI is kept open by the user. I couldn't quite understand the second part of your comment. Perhaps you could illustrate with some pseudo code?

Comment: for (i = 0; i<60; i++){
    //something here to make i ascend 60 times
    Utilites.sleep(3600);
    return app; }

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in HtmlService but not in UiApp.

Comment: How would one accomplish this in HtmlService?

Comment: The setTimeout function works on the client in HtmlService just as it does in regular JavaScript, so you can check the server once a minute as desired.

Comment: Any chance you could give me some example code?  The reason I ask is that I cannot find the setTimeout function in Google Scripts at all.  And this is going on a google Site.

Comment: HtmlService lets you use regular JavaScript and HTML to build your form - it's the plain old JavaScript setTimeout that you can use and nothing specific about Apps Script. I'd recommend reading the HtmlService user guide if this is confusing.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, and I think you're talking about using it to write code outside of the Apps Script.  Which should work, but Google seems to have disabled any kind of code that refreshes pages automatically.  I have tried using the HTML Service to even write JS refresh code and meta code and neither work.

Comment: Nope, I'm saying to write code within Apps Script. Please read the HtmlService page again. Refresh and meta code will not work by design; as I've stated you need to use setTimeout and call google.script.run.someFunctionYouCreate on each interval to do the check.